# Updating a file in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to append a string to the end of a text file stored in S3.
Currently I just read the contents of the file into a String,  append my new text and resave the file back to S3.
Is there a better way to do this.  I am thinkinig when the file is >>> 10MB then reading the entire file would not be a good idea so how should I do this correctly?

Current code
[code]

```
private void saveNoteToFile( String p_note ) throws IOException, ServletException    
{
    String str_infoFileName =  "myfile.json"; 

    String existingNotes = s3Helper.getfileContentFromS3( str_infoFileName  ); 
    existingNotes += p_note;
    writeStringToS3( str_infoFileName , existingNotes );        
}

public void writeStringToS3(String p_fileName, String p_data) throws IOException 
{
  ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( p_data.getBytes());

  try {
      streamFileToS3bucket(  p_fileName, byteArrayInputStream, p_data.getBytes().length);
  } 
  catch (AmazonServiceException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (AmazonClientException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void streamFileToS3bucket( String p_fileName,  InputStream input, long size)
{
    //Create sub folders if there is any in the file name.
    p_fileName = p_fileName.replace("\\", "/");
    if( p_fileName.charAt(0) == '/')
    {
        p_fileName = p_fileName.substring(1, p_fileName.length());
    }
    String folder = getFolderName( p_fileName );
    if( folder.length() > 0)
    {
        if( !doesFolderExist(folder))
        {
            createFolder( folder );
        }
    }
    ObjectMetadata metadata =  new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(size);
    AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read);

    s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, p_fileName , input,metadata).withAccessControlList(acl));
}
```

[/code]

Comment: This article helped me with what I needed https://medium.com/@haldis444/use-lambda-to-append-daily-data-to-csv-file-in-s3-2c2813bc33d0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not possible to append to an existing file on AWS S3. When you upload an object it creates a new version if it already exists:

> If you upload an object with a key name that already exists in the
>   bucket, Amazon S3 creates another version of the object instead of
>   replacing the existing object

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ObjectOperations.html

The objects are immutable.

It's also mentioned in these AWS Forum threads:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=179375
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=540395

Comment: You may be able to get around this however by using Amazon Lambda.  If you were to upload just the changes, you could trigger Lambda code which could append the changes to the target object.  There would still need to be a copy made as mentioned above, but it would be much more efficient than re-uploading the object (depending on its size).

Comment: This would still require a download and re-upload of the object from within Lambda @sthede.  As the answer mentions, objects in S3 are immutable.  They can only be replaced, not modified.

Comment: Seems then that S3 will not be the solution for this usecase. File is expected to get very big.  Back to the drawing board

Comment: Though it is technically true that Lambda would need to download and then upload the object, and that objects are indeed immutable, the operation because it is being done essentially 'on the server' by Lambda would be almost instant.  Similar to doing the fake 'rename' on S3, there is no rename, just a copy in place with a follow up delete (if the name is different), the operation is almost instant despite there being a full copy of an object being made just to essentially change the file name.  Doing the same operation remotely would be unacceptable.

Comment: I think this may be slightly out of date now. It appears that for a single bucket you can disable versioning now which means you can opt out of this behaviour. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-versioning.html

Comment: Currently you can freely replace a file/object (the versioning is off by default) provided the API user has Write access (AmazonS3Fullaccess)

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible to append to an existing file on AWS S3.**

You can delete existing file and upload new file with same name.

**Configuration**

```
    private string bucketName = "my-bucket-name-123";
    private static string awsAccessKey = "AKI............";
    private static string awsSecretKey = "+8Bo..................................";

    IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, 
                                           RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

    string awsFile = "my-folder/sub-folder/textFile.txt";

    string localFilePath = "my-folder/sub-folder/textFile.txt";
```

**To Delete**

```
    public void DeleteRefreshTokenFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var deleteFileRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = awsFile
            };
            DeleteObjectResponse fileDeleteResponse = client.DeleteObject(deleteFileRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**To Upload**

```
        public void UploadRefreshTokenFile()
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(localFilePath);
            try
            {
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
                {
                    InputStream = file.OpenRead(),
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = awsFile
                };
                PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write the new lines/information to a new version of the file.  This would create a LARGE number of versions.  But, essentially, whatever program you are using the file for could read ALL the versions and append them back together when reading it (this seems like a really bad idea as I write it out).

Another option would be to write a new object each time with a time stamp appended to the object name.  `my-log-file-date-time` . Then whatever program is reading from it could append them all together after downloading `my-log-file-*`.

You would want to delete objects older than a certain time just like log rotation.

Depending on how busy your events are this might work.  If you have thousands per second, I don't think this would work.  But if you just have a few events per minute it may be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `s3api put-object`.
First download the version you want and use below commend. it will upload as the latest version.

```
ᐅ aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET --key $FOLDER/$FILE --body $YOUR_LOCAL_DOWNLOADED_VERSION_FILE
```