# How Can I delete a column from csv file in an s3 amazon bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an s3 bucket that contains many CSV files. I want to apply some modifications to these files like removing specific columns from a specific file using aws CLI.

Comment: You can not directly modify files on S3, please refer these [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761076/can-we-update-contents-of-a-specific-file-in-amazon-s3/34761222) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106248/updating-a-file-in-amazon-s3-bucket) threads for more details. But, there is a bit time consuming (due to learning curve) way to achieve it using [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-insert-update-delete-data-on-s3-with-amazon-emr-and-apache-hudi/).

Comment: Furthermore, you can also check [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount s3 and then use.

Comment: @amitd can I download the file that I want to modify, change it and upload it to override the old file version. (I read about aws cli sync command)

Comment: If you would like to way that way, then yes it is possible. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043163/14843902) existing thread for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon S3 API does not have any methods that let you modify the content located in objects. You must get the object, then you can use code to modify the object and put the object back. If you needed to do this to many objects, you can look at using a workflow by using AWS Step functions.